# Inner Join with order by and where clase

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, sql-query-store

I have created a stored procedure for filling a drop down. But the order by clause not working on my procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @compID bigint,
    @after datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpAuc ( ProjectID BIGINT, Title VARCHAR(256))
    INSERT INTO #tmpAuc
    SELECT SA.ID ProjectID, SA.Title 
    FROM [dbo].[Sessions] S
        INNER JOIN Auc SA ON S.AucID = SA.ID
    WHERE S.Session < 3 AND SA.Status > 0 AND SA.CompanyID = @companyID AND S.LiveBeginDate > @after
    ORDER BY LiveBeginDate

    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #tmpAuc
END
```

I would like to order by descending order of LiveBehinDate

Comment: Order by in your final query ;)

Comment: @JohnMathew . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want results in a particular order you have to use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What does "would like to order" mean? Tables have no order. Query results are ordered.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `LiveBeginDate` in the temp table and from the temp table result `ORDER BY LiveBeginDate`

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpAuctions (ProjectID BIGINT, Title VARCHAR(256), LiveBeginDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #tmpAuctions (ProjectID, Title, LiveBeginDate)
SELECT SA.ID AS ProjectID, SA.Title, S.LiveBeginDate
FROM [dbo].[Sessions] S
INNER JOIN [Spectrum_Auctions].[dbo].[Auctions] SA ON S.AuctionID = SA.ID
WHERE S.SessionState < 3 AND SA.Status > 0 AND SA.CompanyID = @companyID AND S.LiveBeginDate > @after

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM #tmpAuctions
ORDER BY LiveBeginDate
```

or avoid temp table and directly use the SELECT with JOIN inside the procedure:

```
SELECT SA.ID AS ProjectID, SA.Title
FROM [dbo].[Sessions] S
INNER JOIN [Spectrum_Auctions].[dbo].[Auctions] SA ON S.AuctionID = SA.ID
WHERE S.SessionState < 3 AND SA.Status > 0 AND SA.CompanyID = @companyID AND S.LiveBeginDate > @after
ORDER BY S.LiveBeginDate
```

Comment: @JohnMathew This should work `INSERT INTO #tmpAuctions (ProjectID, Title, LiveBeginDate)
SELECT SA.ID AS ProjectID, SA.Title, S.LiveBeginDate`. Can you please try with the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

That’s because your data is ordered when writing to the temp table that resides in temp dB. Reading from temp dB is never guaranteed to be in order. So when you select star from your temp table that’s what you get. 
Get rid of the temp table and do the select directly. This will be faster and more efficient as well. If your proc becomes more complex, use CTEs instead of temp tables as they are easier to conceptualize and run much faster in all cases.

Comment: Actually, the order of output rows in a SP of  thread-starter was affected by `DISTINCT ` in a SELECT from temp table. One more thing: Complex CTEs often lead to poor performance and  candidates to be split to smaller steps using temporary tables